# $(window).load() in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Recently I ran into a mysterious problem that IE (6-8) is keeping throwing me an error. I don't know if this is the problem, but I think it is.

Open up the F12 developer tools in a [jQuery included website](http://derek1906.site50.net/), enter

```
$(window).load(function(){
     alert("Wont able to see me");
});
```

And an error will popup:

> "Unable to get value of the property 'slice': object is null or undefined"

Did I do anything wrong, or anything else???

Comment: I don't get that error. But that load handler does not execute since the `'load'` event already occurred (unless you somehow manage to execute that code from the console *while* the page is still loading).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The latest jQuery (1.7.1) with IE10 and IE9 does not produce such an error for me.

**As a side note;** If you wish to execute something when the dom is ready;
Try this way;

```
$(function(){
     alert("Wont able to see me");
});
```

I believe this is the standard convention for attaching a function to domready event.

Reference: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)

Comment: `$(window).load()` and `$(function(){})` isn't the same thing. Document-ready fires before window-load. [Further explanation](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)

Comment: `$(window).load(fm)` is not the same thing as `$(fn)`.  The first one waits until all page resources are loaded (including images).  The second one only waits until the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I'm aware of the difference, however, haven't attached anything to window.onload for a long while, my brain shifted directly to domReady :). I edited the answer as if I did not screw it up the first time.

Answer (score 8):

I recently found a work-around for IE not recognizing `$(window).load()`...

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("See me, hear me, touch me!");
};
```

This is a little different than `$(function(){})` as it executes after all elements are loaded as opposed to when the DOM is ready.

I recently implemented this in another project and it worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still running into this, IE11 (only one I tested) does not fire the the load event if the listener is inside of the jquery ready function. So pull the load function outside of the ready function and it will fire in IE11.

```
//this is bad
$(() => { //jquery ready
    window.onload = () => { //wont fire in IE
        cosole.log('window loaded'); 
    }
});

//this is good
$(() => { //jquery ready
    cosole.log('dom ready'); 
});

window.onload = () => { //will fire in IE
    cosole.log('window loaded'); 
}
```

Comment: Does IE11 even support the arrow notation?

Comment: Sorry, no. You would need es5 syntax in production