# Some of Jquery function is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am developing an application in ASP.Net using C#. Also there are lots of JQuery function used in my application. The application is working fine in Fire Fox and Google Chrome but some of the function is not working in Internet Explorer 10. In my web page I have defined window.bind("load") function. Under this function several JQuery function will execute. This function is working fine in all browsers except IE 10. The code snippet is as follows:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
        //alert("I am In Window Bind Function");
        all_blur();
        get_all_es();
        loadImage();
    });
```

In this code snippet, the alert code is commented. this is not working in IE. But if I put the alert code active then it is working fine. that means the following code working fine for me.

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
        alert("I am In Window Bind Function");
        all_blur();
        get_all_es();
        loadImage();
    });
```

But I have to execute this function without alert. How can I do that? Please help me.

Comment: Can you clarify, if you comment out the `alert` all the code fails - ie the other methods don't get called? But if you leave the alert box in, the other methods do get called?

Comment: Not sure what the complete issue but I would imagine ie doent fire the load event on the window object, I would imagine it would fire on the document object. This also may be dependent on the jquery version you are using but I suggest looking at this stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651012/window-load-in-ie

Comment: @Prescott If I leave the alert box in then all the other Jquery methods get called. without alert box the other jquery method don't get called.

Comment: I have gone through the link on second post and tried with my code but facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In above code when you have alert on , the window gets the time to render the controls on the page, and mean while you click OK on alert, it has all the controls present and the actions can be performed on those.

This is the reason that `$(document).ready(function(){})` must be called instead of load. as following

`$(document).ready(function () {
        //alert("I am In Window Bind Function");
        all_blur();
        get_all_es();
        loadImage();
    });`

Or

```
$(function () {
        //alert("I am In Window Bind Function");
        all_blur();
        get_all_es();
        loadImage();
    });
```

Comment: I have to call this methods after Document.Ready Function. In my application the page is loaded or DOM is loaded through AJAX call. When the DOM gets loaded then only I can execute this methods.

Comment: Yes, if its is loading via Ajax call, Add this function in its Success callback.

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be the time to load all the components. The time taken to come alert is sufficient to load all the components of entire window. It is typical problem in IE especially. So to execute the jQuery after certain time period(you can define it in the following function.)

`setTimeout(function() {
   if ($.browser.msie) { //To confirm the browser as IE(any version)
    //Your jquery/javascript statements
}, 1000);  //This is the time limit, define the time period as per your requirement`