# Google Maps API-v3 not centering in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps, internet-explorer

**Site;**
http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~greatsankey/index.php/contact-us

**JQuery Plugin;** 
http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~greatsankey/templates/greatsankey/js/development/00_jquery.googlemap.js

**Plugin Called in Head with following code;**

```
   (function ( $ ) {

        $(document).ready(loadMap);

        function loadMap() {
            $('#googleMap').googlemap({
                data: [{name:"Great Sankey Leisure Centre",address:"Barrow Hall Lane<br>Great Sankey<br>Warrington<br>WA5 3AA",tel:"01925 724411",url:"",lat:"53.401325",lng:"-2.661248",icon:"http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~greatsankey/images/map-icon.png"}],
                center: {lat: 53.401325, lng: -2.661248 },
                zoom: 11
            }); 
        };          
    }( jQuery ));
```

The map will not load with the correct centre co-ordinatesin IE8.

This also occurs when using $(document).ready(loadMap); in Firefox.

Ive spent the last 4 hours trying to figure this out so any help would be much appreciated.

Sean

Comment: seems to be working fine on FF v34.0.5

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651012/window-load-in-ie), maybe it helps

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with centering Google Maps in various browsers is common. There are different coding techniques recommended to implement Maps in order to make it work on all browsers. Here is one solution that might help in your case.

Try instantiating other functions within the ready(function(){}) block instead of calling from a separate function. Here is an example I have used the GoogleMap function to create a map instance and then setting its center coordinates.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var map = new GoogleMap(document.getElementById('map')); 
  var Warrington = new GLatLng(53.401325,-2.661248); 
  map.setCenter(Warrington, 8); 
});
```

You can give it a try!!Hope that will help :)